# Why does my service activator poll multiple messages?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Given the setup https://gist.github.com/gel-hidden/0a8627cf93f5396d6b73c2a6e71aad3e, I would expect when I send a message that the `ServiceActivator` would be called with a delay of 10 000 between messages.

The first channel takes in a list, then split the messages and then call another `QueueChannel`. But for some reason each pull polls all the split messages. I know I am missing something stupid, or I'm just too stupid to understand whats happening.

Related test case: https://gist.github.com/gel-hidden/de7975fffd0853ec8ce49f9d6fa6531d

Output:

```
2022-10-26 15:22:02.708  INFO 78647 --- [   scheduling-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests    : Received message Hello
2022-10-26 15:22:02.708  INFO 78647 --- [   scheduling-1] com.example.demo.UpdateLocationFlow      : Doing some work for model with id 2
2022-10-26 15:22:03.009  INFO 78647 --- [   scheduling-1] com.example.demo.UpdateLocationFlow      : Completed some work for model with id 2
2022-10-26 15:22:03.017  INFO 78647 --- [   scheduling-1] com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests    : Received message World
2022-10-26 15:22:03.018  INFO 78647 --- [   scheduling-1] com.example.demo.UpdateLocationFlow      : Doing some work for model with id 3
2022-10-26 15:22:03.319  INFO 78647 --- [   scheduling-1] com.example.demo.UpdateLocationFlow      : Completed some work for model with id 3
2022-10-26 15:22:04.322  INFO 78647 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.a.AggregatingMessageHandler        : Expiring MessageGroup with correlationKey[1]
```

My thoughts is that the messages should be something like:

- 00:01 Doing some work for model with id 2
- 00:02 Completed some work for model with id 2
- 00:12 Doing some work for model with id 3
- 00:13 Completed some work for model it id 3

Comment: Ignore that the `groupTimeout` is `1000`.

Comment: I found the problem. The polling endpoint is started twice, so it initiates two polling tasks in different parallel threads. It is not clear why is that since there is a `running` barrier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it is a bug in the Spring Integration around lifecycle management for the `IntegrationFlowAdapter` management. It just starts twice.

As a workaround I suggest to pull your `@ServiceActivator handle()` into an individual component with its own `@Poller` configuration and an `inputChannel` and `outputChannel`. In other words int must go outside of your `UpdateLocationFlow`. This way the `IntegrationFlowAdapter` won't have a control for its lifecycle and won't start it twice.

Meanwhile I'm looking how to fix it.

Thank you for reporting this!

Comment: Here is the fix: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3928